# How to trigger the camera/microphone permissions dialog box in macOS using electron

Tags: angular, electron

**Background:**

I building the electron app which has a permissions page - where I am checking for camera/microphone permission. If permissions are not `granted` then ask for it.

**Codebase on click:**

```
if (systemPreferences.getMediaAccessStatus('camera') !== 'granted') {
    await systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess('camera').then(result => {
        return result;
    });
} else {
    return true;
}
```

**Looking for:**

on button click if permissions not there should open mac camera permissions - which is not doing its job from above.

**Note**: macOS version: 12.0.1

Comment: Can you describe what is happening instead? Are you seeing any error messages? Are you familiar with the DevTools?

Comment: Yes, I am very much familiar, in console seeing no error.

Comment: What is happening instead?

Comment: on clicking the button it does nothing, seems like `systemPreferences.askForMediaAccess` is not doing anythings.

Comment: Which OS version exactly? And could you [edit] your question to include all that information?